# How do I correctly round a float Android?

Tags: android, rounding, number-formatting

Why do these tests behave differently?

```
public void testRoundFloat() {
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    assertEquals("102,345.56", format.format(102345.556f));
}

public void testRoundDouble() {
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    assertEquals("102,345.56", format.format(102345.556d));
}
```

The first test rounding a float fails because the result of the format is xxx.55, the second test rounding a double succeeds. I am running the tests on Android 4.2.2 (level 17)

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's `float` is the standard IEEE 32-bit floating point, which can only maintain roughly 6 decimal digits of accuracy. Your first test is failing because of roundoff representation when it converts the literal `102345.556f` to internal form.

To reduce roundoff errors, use `double` or, for extended precision, [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Good reading: [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

roundedNo = ( ((int)(nFloatt *100)) + 5)/100
is the easiest way to round to 2 decimal places, but there is always error in floating point math just because it is stored and calculated in base 2 and displayed in decimal.